# Describing an unsorted group of elements with varying occurance bounds via XSD 1.0

Tags: regex, xml, xsd

I'm attempting to describe the following kind of structure using XSD 1.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="A" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        <xs:element name="B" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        <xs:element name="C" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

for the following minimal example document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root><D/><D/><D/><C/><D/><D/><A/><B/><D/></root>
```

This does not work, since XSD 1.0 does not allow unbounded occurances of an element inside `<xs:all>`. Since this corresponds to a regex such as `(D*AD*BD*CD*|D*AD*CD*BD*|D*BD*AD*CD*|D*CD*AD*BD*|D*BD*CD*AD*|D*CD*BD*AD*)`, I tried replacing the inner `<xs:all> … </xs:all>` with the following:

```
<xs:choice>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="A" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="B" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="C" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="A" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="C" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="B" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="B" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="A" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="C" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="C" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="A" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="B" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="B" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="C" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="A" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="C" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="B" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="A" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:choice>
```

but when checked using `xmllint`, the tool (quite rightly) complains that *the content model is not determinist*. Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we have some solutions:

### Option 1: Make you regex solution determinist

The following is your regex transforme to a deterministic regex (please allow me this regex abuse of notation):

```
d*
(
    ad*(bd*c|cd*b)
    |
    bd*(ad*c|cd*a)
    |
    cd*(ad*b|bd*a)
)
d*
```

Transformed to XSD:

```
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="A"/>
            <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="B"/>
                    <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    <xs:element name="C"/>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="C"/>
                    <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    <xs:element name="A"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>

        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="B"/>
            <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="A"/>
                    <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    <xs:element name="C"/>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="C"/>
                    <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    <xs:element name="A"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>

        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="C"/>
            <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="A"/>
                    <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    <xs:element name="B"/>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="B"/>
                    <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    <xs:element name="A"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:choice>
    <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

### Option 2: Use xs:key (only valid for simple content or simple types)

**Keys should be unique, always present** (and non-nullable). If a `xs:key` field selects more than one value the document is invalid, so you can use:

```
<xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
       <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
           <xs:element name="A" type="xs:string"/>
           <xs:element name="B" type="xs:string"/>
           <xs:element name="C" type="xs:string"/>
           <xs:element name="D" type="xs:string"/>
       </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:key name="oneABC">
        <xs:selector xpath="."/>
        <xs:field xpath="A"/>
        <xs:field xpath="B"/>
        <xs:field xpath="C"/>
    </xs:key>
</xs:element>
```

### Option 3: Change XML model to enforce order

Not exactly a solution as this won't validate the same documents. This would be a lot easier if you **only accept a given order**. This is only possible if you are the one defining XML document instances structure. Example: `ABCD*`

```
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="A">
    <xs:element name="B">
    <xs:element name="C">
    <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
</xs:sequence>
```

### Option 4: best solution, use XSD 1.1 and xs:assert

Not a real option as you say you need XSD 1.0, but just in case someone can use XSD 1.1. **This is super-easy using XSD 1.1 and xs:assert**:

```
<xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="A"/>
            <xs:element name="B"/>
            <xs:element name="C"/>
            <xs:element name="D"/>
        </xs:choice>
        <xs:assert test="count(A)=1 and count(B)=1 and count(C)=1"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Being locked at XSD 1.0 and not being the one deciding the format, I really like the `<xsd:key>` approach. Although it's clearly an abuse of the concept, the result is much less wordy that the alternative.

Comment: Although it doesn't enforce that A, B, or C appears at least once.

Comment: Validation should fail if A, B or C doesn't appear. What validator are you using?

Comment: You are correct. I only assumed it would not enforce the appearance of A, B, and C.

Comment: Is the behaviour defined, though? I'm reading the spec (https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cvc-identity-constraint) and seems to expect that every field evaluates to a single value. Is what happens if V(N, F) cannot be uniquely resolved specified, or is this an undefined implementation detail.

Comment: Based on Saxon analysis (pre-validation) warning: "The field expression may select multiple nodes, which would make the instance document invalid". Hope that answer your question

Comment: Indeed, here is the corresponding spec clause: "S contains [...] at most one node whose ·governing· type definition is either a simple type definition or a complex type definition with {variety} simple, and no other nodes."

Comment: So, I suppose we can move every `xs:field` into the same `xs:key` to simplyfy this example.

Comment: Your edit suggestion was rejected before I could read it, by three reviewers choosing the reason "This edit deviates from the original intent of the post". I have edited my answer to add that content again. A better edit comment would have been "Simplified the third option, _as discussed in the comments_" otherwise a reviewer may think that you are destroying part of the code.